# Vectorizing a paste0 for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I'm building a simple scraper in R that handles pagination.  I've tried to use paste0 to loop through the paginated url structure.

```
#a vector of the urls to scrape
a <- 1:5


URLs <- function(pages) {
out <- matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 5)
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    fdata <- paste0("https://foo.bar", i, "/")
    out[, i] <- apply(fdata)
}}

df <- lapply(URLs, function(u){

  html.obj <- read_html(u)
  title <- html.obj %>% html_nodes('a.storylink') %>% html_text()
  score <- html.obj %>% html_nodes('span.score') %>% html_text()

 data.frame(title = title, score = score)
})


library(reshape)
data <- merge_recurse(df)

View(data)
```

However, when I try this, the output does not properly populate the URLs variable, and so the rest of the looped data gathering does not execute at all.

I haven't been able to find any other questions here that cover the looping through concatenated items like this.

Can someone provide an idea of where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is `out[, i] <- apply(fdata)`? Your `apply`-call is wrong (without `MARGIN=` and `FUN=`). You should get an error?!

Comment: Are you saying here that I need to specify the expected number of rows in that `apply` call?

Comment: `apply("https://foo.bar1/")` is producing an error for me: *Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default* Does your code works without any error?

Comment: I ended up using the solution provided by @minem and so completely removed that whole part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `URLs` need to be list/vector of links, like:

```
URLs <- paste0("https://foo.bar", a, "/")
# > URLs
# [1] "https://foo.bar1/" "https://foo.bar2/" "https://foo.bar3/" "https://foo.bar4/" "https://foo.bar5/"
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thanks!  So, in other words, I don't need a loop at all to create that vector of URLs?

Comment: @user1725872 yes, if the real pattern are like in your example. ‘paste’ is vectorized

Comment: Makes sense.  One interesting discovery is that if I were to manually set the URLs variable with something like `URLs <- c("https://foo.bar1", "https://foo.bar2", ...)` my data frame scrapes data from every page.  However, when I use your solution here to set the URLs variable, only https://foo.bar1 gets scraped.  Any thoughts as to why that happens?

Comment: @user1725872 then you are probably incorrectly defining `URLs`

Comment: Looks like I just needed to remove the extra "/" at the end of the paste0 function.  All good!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `URLs` function is that it ends with a for loop. This is because a for loop returns `NULL` in `R` once it has finished.

```
x <- for(i in 1:5){
  #do something
}
print(x)
NULL
```

If you end the function with a `return(out)` statement, this might very well solve your problem.

**Edit:** While minem's solution might solve the problem more succinctly, I will leave this answer here as a reminder not to end functions with for loops.

Comment: This is helpful for future reference.  Thanks.